# Change point style on hover over other onpage element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have a list of donors that I pull out from PHP, and I then dynamically assign an id to each, i.e.

```
<div class="rankings-column first">
    <h3 class="ranking vgood">Very good</h3>
    <span id="1" class="0">
        <a href="http://ati.publishwhatyoufund.org/donor/usmcc/" title="U.S., MCC">1. U.S., MCC</a>
    </span>
    <span id="2" class="0">
        <a href="http://ati.publishwhatyoufund.org/donor/gavi/" title="GAVI">2. GAVI</a>
    </span> 
    <span id="3" class="0">
        <a href="http://ati.publishwhatyoufund.org/donor/ukdfid/" title="UK, DFID">3. UK, DFID</a>
    </span>
    <span id="4" class="0">
        <a href="http://ati.publishwhatyoufund.org/donor/undp/" title="UNDP">4. UNDP</a>
    </span>    
</div>
```

Now I have a Highcharts bubble chart. The bubble (point) id is equal to the span id.
My bubble is styled to have no fill and a white border.

When I hover the span, I want the border of the bubble to change to dashed.  How do I do that?  If not possible, I want to change the color or line width.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Highcharts doesn't provide an easy way to set a "dash style" on a marker border (it does for lines but not for markers).  If you really have your heart set on that you'll need to code up a custom marker.

Second, if you want to [update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update) the marker in some other way (like fill or border color) on a `<span>` hover event I would do something like this:

Spans like this:

```
<span id="0" class="aSpan">Span 0</span>
<span id="1" class="aSpan">Span 1</span>
<span id="2" class="aSpan">Span 2</span>
<span id="3" class="aSpan">Span 3</span>
```

Highcharts data like this:

```
data: [{x: Math.random() * 100, y: Math.random() * 100, z: Math.random() * 100, id: 0},
       {x: Math.random() * 100, y: Math.random() * 100, z: Math.random() * 100, id: 1},                  
       {x: Math.random() * 100, y: Math.random() * 100, z: Math.random() * 100, id: 2},
       {x: Math.random() * 100, y: Math.random() * 100, z: Math.random() * 100, id: 3}]
```

Then hover event like:

```
$('.aSpan').hover(function(){
    var myId = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
    var series = Highcharts.charts[0].series[0];
     $.each(series.points, function(_,point){
        if (point.id === myId){
            point.update({marker: {fillColor: 'red'}});
        }
    });
 });
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8sqa7dsx/).